# Not able to set theme to android activity

Tags: android, themes, sharedpreferences, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I want to use shared preferences to set font size.
So I am taking input from user in preferences.

Then I have themes defined in style as below:-

```
    <style name="small_title_text">
      <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#228B22</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
      <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dip</item>
   </style>
   <style name="small_body_text">
      <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor"> #228B22</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
      <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dip</item>
   </style>
   <style name="small_button_text">
      <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor"> #228B22</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>

   </style>

  <style name="small_radio_btn_text">
  <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor"> #228B22 </item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dip</item>
```

```
 <!-- Base application theme is the default theme. -->
```

```
<style name="Theme.SmallText">
 <item name="textTitle">@style/small_title_text</item>
 <item name="textBody">@style/small_body_text</item>
 <item name="buttonText">@style/small_button_text</item>
 <item name="radioButtonText">@style/small_radio_btn_text</item>
```

And in my java code, I am applying this theme as below:

```
if (sharedPrefs.getString("display_setting_font_size","").equalsIgnoreCase("SMALL"))
        {
            act.setTheme(R.style.Theme_SmallText);
            Log.d(" ", "Theme Small text Size is to be is applied.");
        }
```

Where act is Activity.

But as soon as Theme_smallText is applied, my jelly bean app screen looks like ginger bread screen.
Its drop down list and calender view starts looking like ginger bread.

and also, I am not able to see any change in font size.

Can anyone help me in knowing where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
textview.setTextAppearance(mContext, R.style.boldText);
```