# Allow user to set font size, font color, background color for android app

Tags: android, themes, customization, sharedpreferences

I want to allow user to choose font size/color, background color for whole app.

For that, I am getting his preferred values and saving them in default shared preferences provided by android.

But what can be best way to use these values for complete app ?

I tried using it on each activity basis.
this approach is mentioned in [not-able-to-set-theme-to-android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515093/not-able-to-set-theme-to-android-activity) which is not working.

Request you all to pls guide.

Comment: [Reference](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/06/simple-colorpicker-for-android.html) for change background color dynamically.

Comment: You can use shared preference to save these details of font size,background color etc... and to choose color you can give color picker as Gunaseelan said. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to reference. However, I want to make it more simple. just 3 colors, white gray and blue. those r i can save and get from shared pref. but not able to use shared pref values to update font size/color/bg color of app or at least current activity. any reference tutorial available for it?

Comment: You can easily achieve this with Shared preferences, If you can't please Post your code and also tell us to where/what issue you have faced because we can't write full code for you. sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

Please try it.

textview.setTextAppearance(mContext, R.style.boldText);